# partition by a count of a field

Tags: sql-server, partition-by

I have a table t1 with two int fields(id,month) and I have populated it with some values. 
What I would like to see as an output is, the maximum of (count of id in a month). I have tried the following code and it works fine:

```
select id,max(freq) as maxfreq from 
(select id,month,count(*) as freq
from t1
group by id,month) a
group by id
order by maxfreq desc
```

The result is:

```
ID  MAXFREQ
1   3
2   3
3   1
4   1
```

This is fine. How to achieve this using the over partition by clause? And which one is more efficient? In reality my table consists of several thousands of records. So doing a subquery wont be a good idea I guess! Thanks for any help. Here's [the fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f1c/1)

Comment: Show us your table structure with some sample data

Comment: @Raj you can find it in the fiddle.

Comment: you are not able to use over-clause when dealing with group aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH tmp AS (select id, row_number() over (partition by id, month order by id) rn
         FROM t1)
SELECT t.id, max(tmp.rn) as maxfreq
from t1 t
INNER JOIN tmp ON tmp.id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
select id,max(freq) as maxfreq from 
(select id,row_number() over (partition by id,month ORDER BY id) as freq
from t1
) a
group by id
order by id,maxfreq desc
```

but from a performance standpoint, I do not see much difference between your original query and this one.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution but with using CTE. 
Actually there is no point to forcibly use windowing functions to this issue.
Compare both solutions with plan explorer.

;with c1 as
( select id,month,count(*) as freq
from t1
group by id,month 
)
select id, max(freq) as maxfreq
from c1
group by id
order by maxfreq desc;